# Object of type 'environment' is not subsettable with 'checkpoint' package in R

Tags: r, checkpoint

I am trying to write a reproducible `R` script so whenever I run the code I will get the results without any issue once the code is completed. Therefore, I am saving version of packages used in the code into a separate folder using the `checkpoint` package in `R`. The code I am using is as follows.

```
library(checkpoint)
create_checkpoint(snapshot_date = "2022-03-14", r_version = "4.0.4",
                          checkpoint_location = "E:/My Projects/Documents/GeriatricsCohorting_Project_Checkpoint")
```

This works on my personal laptop but doesn't work on a remote desktop. I get the following error:

```
Creating checkpoint directory C:/Users/e22336/Documents/.checkpoint/2022-03-14/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.0.4
Error in x[] <- if (!is.list(x)) x else if (inherits(x, "condition")) "<error>" else if 
(is.recursive(x)) lapply(x,: object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

I am not sure where I make error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The session info and R version is as follows:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (build 9600)

packageVersion("checkpoint")
‘1.0.0’
```

Comment: You need to post the OS and R and package versions for both machines. (And the r_version specified is out-of-date.)

Comment: @IRTFM I added the OS, R, and package info. I know that the R version is not up-to-date. However, I cannot change it at any time since it's a server and runs multiple scheduled tasks.

Comment: I wondered about two aspects: the directory name seems to have a period in front of it. I haven't seen this before but maybe that's an idiosyncrany of its installation? R 4.0.4 was released 2021-02-15 09:05 whereas checkpoint 1.0.0 was released 2021-06-14 09:10 so I'm wondering if the next earlier version of checkpoint would have the same problem?

Comment: As you said the period in the directory is an idiosyncrasy. The `checkpoint` package creates a folder that starts with a period. R version on my laptop is 4.1.0 which was released on 2021-05-18, and the version of the `checkpoint` package is 1.0.0 which was released on 2021-06-14, and it works on my laptop. What I mean is that the `checkpoint` package also works with older R version.

Comment: This verges on "not reproducible". (Actually is is completely "not reproducible. No data to attempt replication.) Supposedly different results with two different devices but only one device described. I think you might be better served by submitting a bug report. See `?maintainer`. Perhaps it's been recognized and fixed?